# How to populate another field within a table with a specific character

Tags: python, calculated-field

I'm trying to modify a table by transferring the address direction in one field to another field.
So lets say the Addresses in the "Address" field of said table is "123 Fake Street S" I need to transfer just the S into a field called "strtDirect". However, some of the addresses do not have a direction associated with them.  So the code I have now is as follows:[Code in Calculate Field tool][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSfsg.jpg

(the pic will give a better picture): So this code transfers the direction into the correct field but when it gets to an address with no direction associated with it, the fields stop being filled out.  I think I need an if statement in there.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  I'm pretty new to this.

```
    def GetStrtDirect(strtAddress):
       aList = strtAddress.split(" ")
       return aList[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want something like:

```
DIRECTIONS = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
def get_strt_direct(strt_address):
   return (
       None 
       if (not strt_address) or (dir := strt_address.split()[-1]) not in DIRECTIONS 
       else dir
   )
```

This ensures the result is `None` if the `strt_address` is empty, or if it doesn't end in one of the given directions. I'm assuming there's only 4 of those here, but of course you may need to add `'NW'`, `'SE'` etc. or possibly even `'East'` etc. In that case, you may want to check if `strtAddress.split()[-1].lower()` is not in that value and return the original value.

- `strt_address.split()[-1]` splits `strt_address` over whitespace and then takes the last one
- `(dir := ..)` assigns the result to `dir`, but also evaluates the result for comparison

A solution with the suggested changes:

```
DIRECTIONS = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W', 'North', 'East', 'South', 'West']
def get_strt_direct(strt_address):
   return (
       None 
       if (not strt_address) or strt_address.split()[-1].lower() not in DIRECTIONS 
       else strt_address.split()[-1]
   )
```

Comment: Appreciated the response, think I can implement that.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel a response has answered your question, consider clicking the checkmark so your question no longer appears unanswered. If the response doesn't quite solve your problem, you may want to add some information to your question to make it more clear why your problem hasn't been resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an address-as-a-string field/value, you will have to write a fairly complicated piece of code to extract the values, yes. In you example, "123 Fake Street S", the street name is made of two words - but it could be one...or maybe three? So yes, you definitely will end up with a lot of conditionals. So if it is at all possible, I would try to make that string use some special character for separating significant values. Like ',' or '|'. So that you can use those values in a split, e.g.

street_number, street_name, street_direction = str_val.split(',')

this will deconstruct a string, like "123|Fake Street|S", into 3 variables.

"21 Main St", naturally, will become "21,Main St,". If your data will include town/sitye/zip code, you'll keep using that convention

Otherwise you "ifs" will quickly become unmanageable. Adding at least some formatting conventions to the data will help you